# Acrobat Context Menu

Tags: pdf

When a user right clicks in acrobat the context menu that pops out, is it customizable
Can I Add menu items to it

Comment: Are you using JS or the C++ API?

Comment: C++ api ( more like C in all honesty :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can when writing a C plugin. You should call AVAppRegisterForContextMenuAddition(...) from within your plugin's init method. IIRC, the plugin dev kit has one or two samples that spell this out in more detail.

Meanwhile, I'm trying to figure out how to do the same from JS.

Comment: Thanks Patrick most of my Adobe plugin related questions rarely get answers on here so nice to talk to someone doing adobe plugin work as well :-)